# Is there any way to view listings of answers directly?

Tags: feature-request

Is there anything analogous to the 'Questions > Recent' and 'Questions > Votes' view of questions?

I was thinking it would make it easier to glance through the newest answers, simply to see them, but also to trawl for answers that deserve up voting which I haven't noticed because I'm not watching that particular question.

(I'm aware that there are a couple review tasks which are similar to this idea. But once reviewed, the questions disappear form the queue so other reviewers don't see them.)